# I'm trying to write a c# program code to find the min distance between the closest numbers in an array and my c# program won't work?

Tags: c#

I'm having problems with my c# code for calculating min   distance between 2 closest numbers in an   array - can someone please help!!  The program is trying to pick random numbers and to generate array i and array j.  Finally, it is trying to determine the min distance between the 2 closest numbers in the array. I don't know why it won't provide the output.

```
namespace Exercise
{
public class Program
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = 0;
        int[] FirstArray = new int[n];
        Random r = new Random();

        int Minimum = int.MaxValue;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
            {

                if (Minimum > Math.Abs(FirstArray[i] - FirstArray[j]))
                {

                    Minimum = Math.Abs(FirstArray[i] - FirstArray[j]);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Minimum = {0}", Minimum);
            Console.Read();
            return 0;
        }
    }

    class Elements
    {
        public double Distance(Elements compar)
        {

            var x1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            var y1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            var x2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            var y2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            var finalResult = Distance(x1, x2, y1, y2);

        }

        private static double Distance(double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2)
        {

            var temp1 = Math.Pow((x2 - x1), 2);
            var temp2 = Math.Pow((y2 - y1), 2);
            var result = Math.Sqrt(temp1 + temp2);

            return result;
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Two tips here

1. At line 8 : The length of FirstArray always '0'.
2. You don't give any value to your FirstArray.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - the array is selecting numbers randomly

Comment: @momals in your `main` method you create the Array `FirstArray` of size `0` (n), but you never fill and/or resize that array. You do create a `Random` instance, but you never use it.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to tell me how to fill and/or resize the array please?

Comment: Hi,  I've tried doing what you've said - can you please let me know if this is correct:

Comment: static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = 0;
            List<int> FirstArray = new List<int>();
            FirstArray.Add(1);
            FirstArray.Add(2);
            Random r = new Random();

            int Minimum = int.MaxValue;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {

                for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
                {

Comment: You just add two fixed values into your FirstArray.
Here demonstrates how to use the Random class to generate ten random values and put it into your `FirstArray`.
`List<int> FirstArray = new List<int>();
            Random r = new Random();
            r.Next(0, 100);

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                FirstArray.Add(r.Next(0,100));
            }
            foreach (int val in FirstArray)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(val);
            }`